# Visual Studio 2017 Professional, IntelliSense не работает в некоторых проектах решения

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Есть решение, в котором имеется множество проектов. В большинстве проектов не работают подсветка и анализ кода: весь код (кроме ключевых слов) - белый; автодополнение не работает; при попытке перейти к определению идентификатора - выводится огромный список идентификаторов, в состав которого входит выделенный.

Я уже удалял папку `.vs`, удалял пользовательские настройки и даже переустанавливал `VS` целиком. Проблема осталась.

С чем эта проблема может быть связана?

Comment: Баганутый Ms studio 2017. Больше 6-7 проектов в решении уже не тянет нормально.

Comment: @MrBin, возможно, вы правы. Я попробовал установить `VS 2019 Community`. В девятнадцатой студии подсветка и анализ работают корректно.

Comment: У меня сейчас открыто решение из 34 проектов, и все работает нормально. Правда C#, а не С++. Странно, что в VS 2019 работает лучше, обычно наоборот на нее жалуются.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, у меня есть 6 случая на четырех разных компьютерах. На чистой Windows 10 в начале все идёт нормально. Потом со временем скорость деградации студии увеличивается и, в конце концов, даже один файл она парсит несколько секунд (Hello world). Я попробовал почти все ответы с форумов майков и он мне не помогли ни в одном случае.